# Scroll within a fixed position overlay

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[JsBin](http://jsbin.com/oPaCAGa/1). Click the buttons on the left. The first one is an example of an overlay that doesn't require a scroll (so it works perfectly), the second button does nothing, and the third button is the problem I'm describing. Note that I copied/pasted the ZenPen style before the main style in the css tab.

I'm using Bootstrap 3.0 and [ZenPen](https://github.com/tholman/zenpen). The idea is that I have a menu on the left side of the screen where you can click a button to hide and show different 'applications' or overlays. These overlays are using `position: fixed`, but I can't do that for the ZenPen overlay or else I won't be able to scroll within it.

If I change `#wordInner { position: fixed;` to `#wordInner { position: absolute;` instead, it will be able to scroll, but it won't take up the entire page (instead centered in the middle of a screen like a normal `container` class. In the JsBin, it's on `position: absolute`, but change it to see the problem I'm talking about.

The logic behind my code is that I use a `col-lg-12`, and style that same div so that it will take the entire page (because a `width: 100%` obviously won't work.)

Main css:

```css
#wrap {
    position: relative;
}
#main {
    position: relative;
}
```

ZenPen's css (a link to the default [ZenPen css](https://github.com/tholman/zenpen/blob/master/css/style.css)):

```css
#word {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-shadow: none;
}

#word b, #word strong {
    color: #000;
}

#wordInner {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    padding: 5px;
    /* because nav is about 100 px, zenpen's icon menu is about 65px */
    padding-left: 165px;
}

#word {
    overflow-y: scroll;

-webkit-transition: all 600ms;
-moz-transition: all 600ms;
-ms-transition: all 600ms;
-o-transition: all 600ms;
    transition: all 600ms;
}

#word section {
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

And relevant html (link to ZenPen html: [ZenPen html](https://github.com/tholman/zenpen/blob/master/index.html)):

```html
 <div class="container" id="wrap">
      <div class="container" id="main">
      <!-- snip irrelevant html -->
      </div>
  </div>

<div class="container" id="apps">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-12"  id="appsInner">
         <div><a href="#" id="close_apps">Close</a></div>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search here" />
       </div>
    </div>
</div>

  <div class="container" id="word">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 yin" id="wordInner" >
    <div><a href="#" id="close_word">Close</a></div>
    <!-- snip zenpen html -->
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="btn light"  id="open_apps"><span class="entypo-search"></span></a><span class='button-text'>Apps</span></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="btn red"  id="home"><span class="entypo-home"></span></a><span class='button-text'>Home</span></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="btn green"  id="open_word"><span class="entypo-leaf"></span></a><span class='button-text'>Word</span></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could set the overflow on `html, body` to `overflow: hidden` and then set `#wordInner { position: fixed; overflow: auto;`. This will ensure that there is only one visible scrollbar on the right hand side of the page, and only when needed. If you need `overflow` set to `visible` for the other pages, you could set it using jQuery (since you are already using it anyway) when you open and close the `#word` app.

### Option 1 (using CSS only): <kbd>[**jsBin**](http://jsbin.com/oPaCAGa/7/)</kbd>

```
html, body
{
  overflow: hidden;
}

#wordInner {  
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  ...
}
```

### Option 2 (using CSS and jQuery): <kbd>[**jsBin**](http://jsbin.com/oPaCAGa/8/)</kbd>

**CSS**

```
#wordInner {  
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  ...
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#open_word").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();   
  $("html, body").css("overflow", "hidden");
  $("#word").show();
});

$("#close_word").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("html, body").css("overflow", "visible");
  $("#word").hide();
});
```